# How can i get json in struts 2 action class through ajax call?

Tags: ajax, json, struts2

I have an application with struts 2 and i want to sensd a json using ajax call to action class.
    My ajax looks like this:

```
var data = {{userName:"userName",password:"password",userId:"userId"},
{userName:"userName",password:"password",userId:"userId"},
{userName:"userName",password:"password",userId:"userId"}
}
 var users= JSON.stringify(data);
                            $.ajax({
                                data: users,
                                type: "POST", 
                                url: "http://localhost:8080/Example_Project/Example.action",
                                contentType: "application/json",
                                dataType: "json" 

                                 })
Action.class





public class ExampleAction extends ActionSupport
                {
                private List<User> users;

                 public List<User> getUsers() {
                return users;
            }
             public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
                this.users = users;
            }

            public String addUsers(){

            //code to inser user list
            return "success";
            }
                }

User.java       




 public class User{

                private String ;//getters and setters for it
                private String password;//getters and setters for it
                private Integer userId;//getters and setters for it

                }

struts.xml





   <struts>
        <package name="default" extends="struts-default,json-default" >
            <action name="Example" class="com.json.action.ExampleAction" method="addUsers">
                    <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
            </action>

        </package>
    </struts>
```

I am using struts2-core 2.3.1.2 ,struts2-json-plugin 2.3.1.2 and json-rpc 1.0.How can i get the users data in action class.With the above code i am getting null in users variable in the action class.Please help.

Comment: You're not sending anything named "users", so I'm not sure why you'd expect it to be anything other than null. Did you try sending an object with a `users` key with a collection of users?

Comment: Then how can i send the above json to action class?Sorry am new to json.

Comment: ... Why would you want to send the JSON you show? It would be better to send something named "users" with an array of users; e.g. something like `{ "users": [{"userName": "xxx", etc.}, {"userName": "yyy", etc.}]}` or something similar (untested).

Comment: still am not getting the json in action class.Is there any problem with my jar?

Answer (score 1):

you need to define result type as shown below in  struts.xml.

```
   <result type="json" />
```

If you still face any issue then please let me know

Comment: But If we want to send the json from action class to jsp then only we need to specify   <result type="json" /> in struts.xml?please clarify my doubt.

Comment: you can specify below snippet and let me know if you still face any issue <action name="Example" class="com.json.action.ExampleAction" method="addUsers">
                 <result type="json" />
            </action>   for more information you can refer folowing link http://mycodefixes.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/using-struts-2-with-json-and-jquery.html